How to force instagram to redirect a link from instagram app to safari using javascript
I am trying to force instagram to redirect a link to safari using Javascript.
I have depployed the below code on netlify and using the hosted link on my instagram bio. Would want the appclip to open on safari from the instagram web-view.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Redirecting...</title>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            const userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
            console.log("User Agent:", userAgent);
            
            const url = "https://xplr.live/p2bdafhuw";
            const playstore = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xircular.xplorecampaign&campaignId=043a10ed-79c6-4b3d-8c16-7ab9d72e96d8&launch=true";
            const appcliplink = "https://appclip.apple.com/id?p=com.xircular.XplorePromote.Clip&campaignId=043a10ed-79c6-4b3d-8c16-7ab9d72e96d8";

            if (/Instagram/i.test(userAgent)) {
                if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
                    // Redirect for Android using intent scheme
                    window.location.href = intent:${playstore}#Intent;package=com.android.chrome;end;
                } else if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(userAgent)) {
                    // Attempt to open the App Clip link directly in Safari
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        window.location.href = appcliplink;
                    }, 100);
                } else {
                    // Handle other platforms
                    alert("Other platform detected.");
                    window.location.href = url;
                }
            } else {
                // Redirect to the URL directly for non-Instagram browsers
                window.location.href = url;
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Redirecting...</h1>
    <h2>I should not see this screen</h2>
</body>
</html>



